# Static content p-message not showing up

Tags: angular, primeng

Static messages for p-messages don't show up in DOM.

Angular Version: 15
PrimeNg Version: 15

Link to component: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-v15-lts/messages#static

Answer (score 1):

Including `ToastModule` in your module will do the magic.

`import { ToastModule } from 'primeng/toast';`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug with the `MessagesModule`. You can use this import `import { SharedModule } from 'primeng/api'` (or import the `ToastModule` as Api said). You can see this Github issue for the details on what the bug is:

https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/13858